# SailsJS: POST requests are not resolved properly when invoking req.param() and req.file()

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http, sails.js

I use PostMan to test my controller, which reads data from the POST request by using req.param() and req.file().
Weirdly, the order of the parameters I submit matters. For example,

Case 1:

```
file: some file attached
property1: 1
```

The file would be resolved properly while property1 wouldn't (undefined).

Case 2:

```
file: some file attached
property1: 1
property2: 2
```

req.param('property2') would return 1 (yes, 1, no typo here) for the first requests and undefined for the subsequent ones.

Case 3:

```
property1: 1
file: some file attached
```

This way, everything works fine.

Is it an expected behavior or a bug? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Skipper (the file upload system in Sails) you need to send all of your text parameters before the file parameter. Case three in your examples should be how you always send the request. For more information see the Skipper Docs:

https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper#text-parameters

Comment: You saved me. I should have read the documentation thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

`req.param()` is for PATH parameters. I'm guessing you are trying to get post data here, so you should be using `req.body('key')`.

Comment: I remembered that SailsJS does not
distinguish between GET and POST parameters. Using req.param() I am able to get other POST parameters.

Comment: For a url such as: `http:localhost.com/:id/home?property1=this`, `req.param()` is used for PATH parameters (`:id`). `req.query()` is for QUERY parameters (`property1`). Finally, `req.body` is for POST DATA, such as what you're probably looking for.